# How to get max resolution of MediaCodec before configuring

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, encoder-decoder

My app create several instance of [MediaCodec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) which work parallel as video/audio decoders and encoders.

I know that video codec has limiting buffer space and this limit depends on device.

For example on tab Samsung SM-P600 I can create four MediaCodecs with resolution 720p:

> 1280*720*4=3686400

but not five:

> 1280*720*5=4608000

Because codec will return error during configuring:

```
E/OMX:  setParam  sum(4608000) > max resolution(4177920)
E/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.AVC.Encoder] failed to set input port definition parameters.
E/ACodec:  configureCodec multi window instance fail  appPid : 17054
E/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.AVC.Encoder] configureCodec returning error -1021
E/ACodec: signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -1021)
E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0xfffffc03, actionCode 0, while in state 3
E/MediaCodec: configure failed with err 0xfffffc03, resetting...
```

How can I get **max resolution(4177920)** before configuring MediaCodecs to count max available resolutions for all MediaCodecs I need?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am also unable to find a MediaCodec interface to get this max resolution sum.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use getMaxSupportedInstances () in MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.html

Or isSizeSupported(int width, 
                int height) in MediaCodecInfo.VideoCapabilities.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.VideoCapabilities.html

Comment: It is good solution "use getMaxSupportedInstances ()", but not all devises return this info, for example Samsung p600 doesn't.

Comment: `getMaxSupportedInstances () ` has nothing to do with resolutions

Comment: getMaxSupportedInstances() returns the number of codecs that can run in parallel